# How to use aws network loadbalancer to send trafic to a non aws endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

think I have a very unusual request.
We want to use a AWS network loadbalancer to send traffic to 2 endpoints in a NONE AWS environment. So the endpoints are not in an AWS VPC.
Requirment is that calls to the 2 endpoints must be round robin. Both endpoints are HTTP POST endpoints and they have a different hostname but the URL prefix is the same. Something like this.
Endpoint 1 = http://www.example1.com/test/uri and Endpoint 2 = http://www.example2.com/test/uri .
I am struggling in the AWS console and tried things with the AWS network loadbalancer and create a targetgroup and a api gateway with a http API and a Rest API but I can't get it working.

I think it is not possible to achieve such a configuration in AWS, but maybe somebody has an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: We achieved the same by configureing[targets using IP addresses](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type). But we have direct-connect established between DC and AWS.

Comment: You can only do this with a NLB if you can reference the two endpoints via IP address instead of domain name.

Comment: Yes but the IP addresses must be private according the link Sam send me. Problem is my IP addresses are public internet facing adresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly. It is explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-type):

> You **can't specify publicly** routable IP addresses.

You would have to setup **VPN** or some other type of **proxy** on AWS rough your connections to these the public endpoints.

Comment: Thanks Marcin for you answer so I have to find another solution for this. Like you say having an extra proxy in AWS or something like that.